# Search count of words within a string using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Database: Sql Server

I have table column named page_text which contains following value

> " I Love stackoverflow.com because i can post questions and get
>   answers at any time. "

Using **SQLQUERY**  i want to search the number of **`I`** it has . So in this string it would should return 4.

I should be able to search anything.

Comment: the initial post stated the result should be 2. which would count the words.
now it says 4 which would count the appearances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
declare @search varchar(10) = 'I'

select len(replace(PageText, @search, @search + '#')) 
- len(PageText) as Count from YourTable
```

Comment: +1 Seems to deal with the trailing space issue my answer missed.

Answer (score 0):

based on this code: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-character.aspx

you create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CountSpecificWords] ( @pInput VARCHAR(1000), @pWord VARCHAR(1000) )
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

RETURN (LEN(@pInput) - LEN(REPLACE(@pInput, ' ' + @pWord + ' ', '')))

END
GO
```

this however implies that you save your strings with a leading and trailing space and you replace any other separators like ',' and '.' with spaces.

and you need to refrase your question if you want the count of words or just the appeareance of a word.

Comment: this code counts the words, as it was specified in the initial text

Comment: try this input 'H H H H H H H H H H * 10' and this word 'H' It will return 15

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (LEN(@Text) - LEN(REPLACE(@Text,@SearchString,''))/(Len(@SearchString))
```