# Count of string match in all columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search count of words within a string using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766959/search-count-of-words-within-a-string-using-sql)

I have a table TABLE1 as follows

```
Col1    Col2
1   Hai Hello Hai
2   Hello Hai Hai Hai
3   R R R
4   R R R
5   Hello Hello Hello
```

Now If I am searching for  a workd "Hai" I want the result as follows

```
Col1    Col2            Cout_of_Stirng_Match
1   Hai Hello Hai       2
2   Hello Hai Hai Hai   3
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select col1, len(replace(col2, @word, @word + @not_used_char)) 
- len(col2) where len(replace(col2, @word, @word + @not_used_char)) 
- len(col2) > 0 as Cout_of_String_Match
```

See [Search count of words within a string using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766959/search-count-of-words-within-a-string-using-sql)

Answer (score 1):

create a function as below and rest is a simple query  , do that yourself

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CountString]
    ( @pInput VARCHAR(8000), @pSearchString VARCHAR(100) )
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN

        RETURN (LEN(@pInput) - 
                LEN(REPLACE(@pInput, @pSearchString, ''))) /
                LEN(@pSearchString)

    END
    GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help: 1 more small question ( slight modification in the actual question).If I am searching for the words both "hai" OR "Hello" ( At a time by using OR condition)
I want the result as follows:
Col1 Col2   Matched_Word
1 Hai Hello Hai  Hai, Hello
2 Hello Hai Hai Hai Hai, Hello
5 Hello Hello Hello Hello